# Does the ST4000NM0033 really use 512 byte sectors, and does it matter?

Tags: hard-drive

I recently purchased and installed a Seagate Constellation ES.3 4 TB drive, model ST4000NM0033. Right now it's suffering under a write stress test (overwrite pass of the entire drive with Write-Read-Verify turned on to allow the drive firmware to identify any bad sectors before I put anything important on the drive), but I was really surprised when I checked the SMART data and it reported that the drive uses a 512 byte logical and physical sector size. I thought that with such large drives, 4096 byte sectors was the name of the game. Running `smartctl --all /dev/XXX` on Debian Wheezy, I get:

```
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.2.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST4000NM0033-9ZM170
Serial Number:    XXXXXXXX
LU WWN Device Id: X XXXXXX XXXXXXXXX
Firmware Version: SN03
User Capacity:    4 000 787 030 016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
```

- Does this model drive really use a 512 bytes physical sector size?
- Do I even need to concern myself with such details?

I'm planning to align everything *as if* the drive was a 4 KiB physical sector size drive, if nothing else for consistency, but the smartctl output has me somewhat puzzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Seagate the [ST4000NM0033](http://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/product-content/constellation-fam/constellation-es/constellation-es-3/en-us/docs/100671511a.pdf) drive does indeed use a 512 byte sector size.  It seems that *smartctl* is reporting correctly.  I don't know if you need to concern yourself with these details however.

Comment: It would appear that you are correct; section 2.1 table 1 specifically says "sector size: 512". In which case my second question becomes moot.